# TECs: parallel or series?

Tags: parallel, series, peltier, thermocouple, cooling

My project is regarding the cooling effect of TECs. I am from a mechanical background.

My question is: what happens when TECs are connected in series or in parallel? If one configuration is better than the other, please explain why it is so.

Comment: Welcome. Define better. Have you tried to simulate your TECs in both configurations and vary their parameters according to the datasheets max and min parameters? They won't be perfectly matched in real life.

Comment: You should probably first get some idea what these types of connection mean in general. From the question it looks like you don't know.

Comment: You mean electrically series/parallel or heat-wise series/parallel? as you can physically stack the cold side of one to the hot side of another (series) and you can also put two of them next to each other (parallel)

Answer (score 1):

They're kind of like pumps in that you use their I/Q or V/Q curves ([example](https://www.lairdthermal.com/datasheets/datasheet-PT6-12-F2-4040-TA-W6.pdf)) to figure out how much heat will be pumped across a given temperature gradient, much like a pump curve determines the operating point of the system.  The big wrinkle for stacking TECs is that they are not very efficient and so each successive (hotter) stage requires a larger TEC:

[image: three-stage TEC]

Image source: Laird